# SettingWithCopyWarning when one column of DataFrame is strings

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, indexing

I get a SettingWithCopyWarning for the following code:

```
rain = DataFrame({'data':['1','2','3','4'],
                  'value':[1,-1,1,1]})
rain.value[rain.value < 0] = 0
```

While I don't get that warning with

```
rain = DataFrame({'data':[1,2,3,4],
              'value':[1,-1,1,1]})
rain.value[rain.value < 0] = 0
```

The only difference is that the 'data' column is strings in the first DataFrame, and numbers in the second DataFrame. Am I doing something wrong? Is there a different (preferred?) way to do this? Shouldn't the warning at least be applied consistently?

Comment: http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#indexing-view-versus-copy  -  "A chained assignment can also crop up in setting in a mixed dtype frame"

Answer (score 2):

You are doing something wrong on **both** occasions. The fact you receive a warning in one of the two scenarios is not relevant. You should **never** use chained indexing. In fact, it is [explicitly discouraged](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#indexing-view-versus-copy) in the docs.

Instead, you can use [`pd.DataFrame.loc`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html):

```
rain.loc[rain.value < 0, 'value'] = 0
```

I see no warnings or errors in either scenario with this method. An even better idea, to avoid expensive Boolean indexing, is to use [`np.maximum`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.maximum.html):

```
rain['value'] = np.maximum(0, rain['value'])
```

Answer (score 1):

**In the case of this question:**

```
rain.value[rain.value < 0] = 0  # doesn't work

rain.loc[rain.value < 0] = 0  # works
```

**Why Does One Work and Not the Other:**

From the pandas documentation at [Indexing and Selecting Data](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#evaluation-order-matters) - Section Evaluation order Matters

A chained assignment can also crop up in setting in a mixed dtype frame.

Note These setting rules apply to all of .loc/.iloc.

**This is the correct access method:**

```
In [345]: dfc = pd.DataFrame({'A':['aaa','bbb','ccc'],'B':[1,2,3]})

In [346]: dfc.loc[0,'A'] = 11

In [347]: dfc
Out[347]: 
     A  B
0   11  1
1  bbb  2
2  ccc  3
```

**This can work at times, but it is not guaranteed to, and therefore should be avoided:**

```
In [348]: dfc = dfc.copy()

In [349]: dfc['A'][0] = 111

In [350]: dfc
Out[350]: 
     A  B
0  111  1
1  bbb  2
2  ccc  3
```

**This will not work at all, and so should be avoided:**

```
>>> pd.set_option('mode.chained_assignment','raise')
>>> dfc.loc[0]['A'] = 1111
Traceback (most recent call last)
     ...
SettingWithCopyException:
     A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame.
     Try using .loc[row_index,col_indexer] = value instead
```

Warning The chained assignment warnings / exceptions are aiming to inform the user of a possibly invalid assignment. There may be false positives; situations where a chained assignment is inadvertently reported.